# Why does my function on resize applies on hover (js, svg)

Tags: javascript, svg

So I have this function which aim is to resize an svg element on window resize :

```
bP.resize = function(){
    var currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;

    var delta = prevHeight - currentHeight;
    var wantedHeight = currentHeight - delta - 400;
    var ratio = wantedHeight / height;

    svg.style('transform', 'scale(0,' + ratio + ')');
    height = wantedHeight;
    prevHeight = currentHeight;
    prevWidth = currentWidth;
};
```

and that call :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', bP.resize);
```

the thing is, resize only applies when I resize my window AND hover the svg.

Comment: Sounds like there's something else going on. Could you post [a minimal test-case](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You shouldn't use window `resize`, it fires way too many events. Try using a custom event like `debouncedresize` or `throttledresize`.

Comment: Why not applying a width: <value>% via CSS instead?

Comment: Anko is right I can't create a minimal test case (it works :( ). My problem comes from elsewhere. Sorry for disturbing, thanks for the help. I don't want to aply % values from css because i need to substract 400px (menu + browser layout) from the result. I'm going to try the debouncedresize but i don't think it will work since I managed to do what i want without it on a smaller project.